# AWS Security Group for RDS - Outbound rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a security group assigned to an RDS instance which allows port 5432 traffic from our EC2 instances.

However, this security group has all outbound traffic enabled for all traffic for all IP's.

Is this a security risk? What should be the ideal outbound security rule? In my perspective, the outbound traffic for the RDS security group should be limited to port 5432 to our EC2 instances, is this right?

Answer (score 9):

> Is this a security risk?

Potentially, yes.  Some configurations, such as [Postgres foreign data wrappers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Extensions.foreign-data-wrappers.html) could allow your RDS instance to establish outbound connections, and anything you allow that you don't actually need to allow is a potential risk.

> What should be the ideal outbound security rule?

Nothing should be allowed, unless your database needs to *initiate* outbound connections, which would only be in circumstances like using the foreign data wrappers functionality to allow one database server to reach out to a different database server to federate access to external (foreign) data.

> In my perspective, the outbound traffic for the RDS security group should be limited to port 5432 to our EC2 instances, is this right?

Almost correct, but technically incorrect (or ambiguously stated).

The instances aren't using port 5432 on their side.  That's the destination port.  The source port on the instance side typically changes with each connection.

Security groups are stateful and their rules are only needed to allow the *initiation* of connections.  Response traffic is automatically allowed, without configuration.

> “Security groups are stateful — responses to allowed inbound traffic are allowed to flow outbound regardless of outbound rules, and vice versa.”

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#VPCSecurityGroups

Inbound connections to the database have a destination port of 5432.  The single inbound rule thus allows these connections to be established *and* the reply traffic to be returned.

The outbound "allow" rule in the database security group is not needed in order for the database to respond to those inbound connections.  Security group rules control connection initiation.

This even remains true even in the case of replication within RDS.  The RDS machines clearly must connect to each other in such a configuration, but it turns out they have their own "hidden" network across which they can establish these connections, and it does not depend on your security group settings.

Comment: +1 for "Security groups are stateful and their rules are only needed to allow the initiation of connections"

Comment: `nothing outbound should need to be allowed` - I think this answer is outdated. If your DB uses foreign data wrappers for remote Postgres DBs or other DBMSs, Postgres will need outbound connections that reach see those hosts.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson thanks, updated.